# Sending Typescript number input to a backend using decimal with comma

Tags: typescript, localization, numbers, decimal-point

I'm a bit stuck with a conversion problem.

The backend in our project uses decimals with comma. In the front end side there are fields in the model mapped to Number and accept decimals as well. This means, if I use the `Number()` function, it converts decimal numbers with dot from strings. ("1.2" --> 1.2 OR "1,2" --> NaN)

I would like to send the form value to the backend and I already got rid of different localisation symbols. But the backend doesn't accept the decimal format with dot, it requires the 1,2 format. It's not possible to send it as string either.
The backend cannot be changed (not even the rest API), this has to be handled in the front end side.
Any idea for a conversion method?
Many thanks!

Comment: can you provide more informations about what you want the frontend to do ?

Comment: What does "it requires the 1,2 format" and "It's not possible to send it as string either" mean? Either the backend takes a number, in which case the format doesn't matter or it takes a string in which case you can convert the number to string and swap the dots and commas.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `replace()` methode on strings.

```
new Number('1,2'.replace(',','.'))
```

Comment: JavaScript just doesn't support number format with comma

Comment: you can replace the comma with a dot.

Comment: `But the backend doesn't accept the decimal format with dot, it requires the 1,2 format. It's not possible to send it as string either.`

Comment: `It's not possible to send it as string either` that mean she needs to send it as a number ? no ?